# Sound ID failing in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I have the following code linked up to a button that should play some audio.

```
var ExamplePlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var Example = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Example", ofType: "mp3")!)

func ExampleAudio(){

    ExamplePlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: Example, error: nil)
    ExamplePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    ExamplePlayer.play()
}

@IBAction func anotherExampleAudio(sender: AnyObject) {

    ExampleAudio()
}
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What's going on?

Comment: you should use NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(withExtension)

Comment: You are trying to load an URL Projects but it should be Example. BTW you should name your vars starting with a lowercase letter. If the URL will never change you should use let

Comment: It is example, just forgot to change that from my Xcode project.

Comment: You still need to unwrap your optional using if let or just force unwrap it with "!" considering the fact that it is a local resource. Change it to URLForResource